# How can I reconstruct raw headers from request into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, request

I am trying to reconstruct the raw headers from the request object from looking like this:

```
[{"0": "Host"},
 {"1": "localhost:3000"},
 {"2": "Connection"},
 {"3": "keep-alive"}, 
{"4": "sec-ch-ua"}, 
{"5": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"102\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"102\""}]
```

to something like:

```
[{ "Host: "localhost:3000"}, {"Connection": "Keep alive"}]
```

is this possible in javascript?

Comment: Do you have a list of the valid headers that will be passed back, and will the headers always be at the start, and will there be 2 every time or a variable amount... ?

Comment: Hi, there'll be a variable amount each time. I am just trying to display them on a webpage so they look like: 
Host: localhost:3000 etc

Comment: There are lots of kinds of request objects, which one specifically are you referring to? The one in Express and/or Node.js? Something else?

Comment: hi, the one in Express

Comment: So, that's [an enhanced version](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) of Node.js's `IncomingMessage`, which has [`headers`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#messageheaders). What *specific* problem are you having reformulating that information into what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) them to an array of [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and then [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) them pairwise to your desired result object:

```js
const headers = [
  {"0": "Host"},
  {"1": "localhost:3000"},
  {"2": "Connection"},
  {"3": "keep-alive"}, 
  {"4": "sec-ch-ua"}, 
  {"5": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"102\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"102\""}
];

const result = headers.flatMap(Object.values).reduce((r, _, i, a) => 
  i % 2 ? r : {
    ...r,
    [a[i]]: a[i + 1]
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```